# GET request after every few seconds

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval

I want to send GET request and in the json value that I recieved, if it contains status as true then I want to redirect to another page.

Also I want to send the api request after 5 sec then 10 sec then 11 sec and go on till not recieved status as true.

My try:

```
  async function getStatus() {
json = await `GET API REQUEST SENT`;
if (json.status === true) {
  clearInterval(statusApi);
}


}

let time = 0;

statusApi = setInterval(() => {
  getStatus();
  time += 5000;
}, time);

if (json.status === true) {
  return (
    <Redirect
      to={'/forward'}
    />
  );
}
```

The problem is here is that it does not redirect to another page.

Also when it is returning nothing is shown on the page (After this code return is written nect which is shown on that page)

Comment: Your example incomplete, which makes it really hard for anyone to help. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @EmileBergeron What else should I add?

Comment: Some code that I can test on my end, as-is, ideally.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want to redirect to another path, you can simply change the state to re-render the component, thus rendering the  component.

```
this.setState({ redirect: "/someRoute" })
```

https://dev.to/projectescape/programmatic-navigation-in-react-3p1l

Answer (score 0):

Just add a state to your component and add Redirect tag based upon that state.

```
const Comp = () => {
    const [doRedirect, setDoRedirect] = React.useState(false)
    return (
        doRedirect && <Redirect
        to={'/forward'}
      />
    )
}
```